# How to get this from an anonymous method of abstract parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an abstract Activity called Animal and two concrete descendant Activities Cat and Dog.

Cat & Dog are to present the same UI, consisting of a single button and so there is a single layout, activity_animal.xml that Animal sets as it's content view in OnCreate.

I want to set the button's OnClickListener in the abstract Animal class by means of an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener

```
private void setClickHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn))
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //how to get a reference to this?
        }
    });
}
```

and in onClick I want to make a new Intent. To make the Intent I need a reference to **this**.
Normally, in anonymous method code like this, I could use syntax such as
**EnclosingClass.this**
but here, I don't know what the enclosing class will be. At run time, it could be either a Cat or a Dog.

How to do this?

The only way I can think of is to provide an abstract getThis() in Animal which is overridden in each concrete descendant.

Comment: `Animal.this` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for these answers.
I'd not realized that I could simply use Animal.this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to say `Animal.this` as your context.

```
private void setClickHandlers() {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Animal.this, MyDestinationActivity.class);
            ...
        }

    });
}
```

`Animal.this` will be either a `Cat` or `Dog` but since you only need `Context` the distinction is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Activity host = (Activity) arg0.getContext();
}
```

Comment: this would also work, but no need to cast to an Activity as the intent only needs the Context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like:

```
private void setClickHandlers() {
  final Animal thiz = this;
  ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn))
  .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( thiz, AAAA.class );
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the runtime type by using the `instanceof` operator.

```
if (Animal.this instanceof Dog) {
   // dog related 
}
else {
   // cat related
}
```